# Prints only one value from the record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Here, I want to print those value which are in table.
So, my query is like this:

```
$get_role_query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (333,1,2)"; 
$roleres = mysqli_query($conn,$get_role_query);
$r_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($roleres);
```

Here, `333` is not in table but `1` and `2` are in table.
When I am printing this like,

`print_r($r_id);`

It only gives me `1` but not getting `2` which is also in table. I don't want `333` that is fine. But I am getting only `1`, not getting `2`.

**UPDATED BELOW:**

As you all suggest to use while loop, I did like this:

```
$r_role = mysqli_num_rows($roleres);

for($i=0;$i<=$r_role;$i++)
{
    print_r($r_id);
}
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
)
```

From above query, I just want output like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you'll need to continually fetch rows, you've only invoked once. use `while`

Comment: What output do you actually want here?

Comment: You have to do it using a loop, The result should be multiple rows, but you just retrieve one.

Comment: Whoever downvioted the answers, please help me with the reason for the same.

Comment: I might surely need the reason for down vote..

Comment: Please be specific onto reason for the down vote. Don't do as required for you.

Comment: The first guy to put the answer to this post was me but due to down vote of 2 you have accepted the answer for @SujeetSinha.. What a strange strategy that you have followed... Happy to help you :)

Comment: @Ghost I am asking you not pointing you here. I have two up-votes and three down votes but the developers who made that are still out of reasons. Is this a right strategy to follow. Since he has tried some thing i have applied for the answer but these developers who are here are out of reasons for the down vote. Please don't do like this if you don't have reasons for down-vote.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P: 
[Take a Look](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334509/should-have-reason-for-every-downvote-of-question?noredirect=1#comment395133_334509) with this.
The same issue was with me.

Comment: @Virb. You should have accpeted my answer right but the downvote has diverted you to vote for someone... Since it has given negative impact over to my answer even if my answer is correct.

Comment: Link does not work @Virb.

Comment: Because of the negative vote that these developers do my correct answer becomes wrong and you too have thought the same and voted for @SujeetSinha. Even thought he has delivered the answer behind me... Horrible situations

Comment: Man, I upvoted you and you can see that I tried the code that already I written in my question, though they are down voting my question.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P I do agree that the downvote on all of the answers was unnecessary and uncalled for.. You can see my comments on the same issue.. I have upvoted each of the answer personally because of this, but just pointing everytime time that I received help is not fair. I have 2 downvotes myself  but nothing can be done about it.. We are to help and get help.. Let's keep it to that.. Happy coding and helping :)

Comment: @SujeetSinha. Since there is none reason behind every down-vote  for all that is the reason am holding onto it in order to help all to knwo the reason. If atleast they have given the reason it would help all of us right. We sould not give back our rights for asking the queries if we are correct. I am fond of helping and i will keep doing that even if i get this kind of incidents over here. What i am suggesting here is that if you down-vote please provide specific reason over there.

Comment: and i agree with you.. this entire thing is not needed, but holding on to it is not going to help anyone.. same time can be used on some other question to help someone else.. :)

Comment: @SujeetSinha. Ya that is also fine.. Thanks... Let us njoy coding and helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` correctly. It fetches one record at a time. Use it as follows:

```
while($r_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($roleres))
{
   print_r($r_id);
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvioted, please help me with the reason for the same.

Comment: This works fine..!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Use while in order to fetch multiple values from the table:

```
$get_role_query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (333,1,2)"; 
$roleres = mysqli_query($conn,$get_role_query);
while($r_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($roleres))
{
   echo $r_id['id'];
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Why the reason for down vote =??

Comment: Still one more down vote . Can you pls just explain it .. Since it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Naresh. Your code works..!!

Comment: You can accept if the code works ... But you have not done that..

Comment: @Anant.. what i am arguing is correct right .. Since for helping other we are discouraged means it creates bad impact over us right

Comment: @NareshKumar.P  you are right.

Comment: This scenario was mine over here... The first guy to put the answer to this post was me but due to down vote of 2 you have accepted the answer for @SujeetSinha.. What a strange strategy that you have followed.

Comment: This alone i cant accept today.. Really miserable feeling over here for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an object method instead array method.

```
$get_role_query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (333,1,2)"; 

if ($result = $mysqli->query($get_role_query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
         echo  $obj->id;
    }
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();
```